# php soapclient error decoding

Tags: php, soap

I am using php's soapclient to invoke some web services

One of the service returns the below error

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>
                soap:Server
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                Validation Error
            </faultstring>
            <detail>
                <errorCode>
                    90
                </errorCode>
                <errorMessage>
                    Error
                </errorMessage>
                <errors>
                    <error field="emailAddress">Email already exists</error>
                    <error field="name">Name already exists</error>
                </errors>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, when the soap client decodes the message, it does not include the field attributes
to the error array

I just get an array with the error description, without the error fields

Is there an option I need so that I can get them also?

Thanks